# How to split x number of integers into y number of arrays?

Tags: java

Scenario:

I have X number of elements. I need to partition/split up these elements as evenly as possible, exactly Y number of times (no more). Any remainder should be added to the last index.

Question: What is the optimal way to do this

Code Example I have tried

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    Integer[] payload1 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24};
    Integer[] payload2 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    Integer[] payload3 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    Integer[] payload4 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
    Integer[] payload5 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24};

    ArrayList<Integer[]> payloads = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    payloads.add(payload1);
    payloads.add(payload2);
    payloads.add(payload3);
    payloads.add(payload4);
    payloads.add(payload5);

    int splits = 5;

    for(Integer[] x : payloads){

        int counter = 1;
        for(ArrayList<Integer> i : Segmenter.splitter(x, splits))
            System.out.println(counter+++" "+i.toString()+" Size : "+i.size());

        System.out.println("");
    }
   }

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> splitter(Intger[] payload, int splits){

        int distibution = (payload.length + splits - 1) / splits;
        System.out.println("Distibution : "+distibution);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> assembledArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        int size = (payload.length + splits - 1) / splits;

        for(int i = 0; i < payload.length; i++)
        {
            if(i % size == 0)
                assembledArray.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            assembledArray.get(i / size).add(payload[i]);
        }

        return assembledArray;
    }
}
```

Furthered developed question thanks to abagshaw & selbie

**Results From Above**

```
Steps : 5
1 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
2 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
3 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
4 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
5 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

Steps : 3
1 [0, 1, 2]
2 [3, 4, 5]
3 [6, 7, 8]
4 [9, 10, 11]
5 [12]
```

**Problem : Notice there should be 6 resulting arrays (hence splits=6). The above returns only 5 arrays in this edge case**

**Desire Results Example**

When 15 elements (plus 0th index) need to be split 6 times

```
1 [0, 1, 2]
2 [3, 4, 5]
3 [6, 7, 8]
4 [9, 10, 11]
5 [12, 13, 14]
6 [15]
```

When 12 elements (plus 0th index) need to be split 6 time

```
1 [0, 1]
2 [2, 3]
3 [4, 5]
4 [6, 7]
5 [8, 9]
6 [10, 11, 12]
```

When 11 elements (plus 0th index) need to be split 6 times

```
1 [0, 1]
2 [2, 3]
3 [4, 5]
4 [6, 7]
5 [8, 9]
6 [10, 11]
```

when 15 elements (plus 0th index) need to be split 8 times

```
1 [0, 1]
2 [2, 3]
3 [4, 5]
4 [6, 7]
5 [8, 9]
6 [10, 11]
7 [12, 13]
8 [14, 15]
```

And so on..

**Solution (Thanks to selbie)**

https://ideone.com/Bul3NU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use floating point (double) to compute the values of `steps`.  Replace this line:

```
int steps = (int) Math.ceil(payloadSize/(double)splits);
```

With this:

```
steps = payloadSize / splits;
```

And then your for loop is more or less what you have. Here's some light adjustments:

```
protected ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> splitter(int [] payload, int splits)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> segment = null;

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> assembledArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    int steps = payload.length / splits;


    for(int i=0; i<payload.length; i++) {

        if (segment == null) {
            segment = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            assembledArray.add(segment);
        }

        segment.add(payload[i]);

        if ((segment.size()>=steps) && (assembledArray.size() < splits))
            // null out the segment to indicate a new one must be created
            // unless we are on the last split index
            segment = null;
    }
}
return assembledArray;
```

Comment: If you try with the payload of 0-24 and a split of 6. we still end up with 5 :-/

Comment: Oops, I was rounding up instead of down.  Adjusted solution.

Comment: I think that was the missing piece. Awesome job! Just ran multiple tests on the code and it appears to be evenly distributing everything correctly

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more straight forward solution that's a bit cleaner:

**Edit: splitter conforms with the rule where splits always equals the output assembledArray.length and all desired outcomes should work.**

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> splitter(int[] payload, int splits){

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> assembledArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    int[] sizes = new int[splits];
    int j = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < payload.length; j++)
    {
        if(payload.length - j < splits && j % (splits - 1) == 0)
            break;
        sizes[splits - (j % (splits - 1)) - 2]++;
    }
    sizes[sizes.length - 1] = payload.length - j;

    int currentOn = 0;
    int currentIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < payload.length; i++)
    {
        if(currentOn == 0)
        {
            assembledArray.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            currentOn = sizes[currentIndex];
            currentIndex++;
        }
        assembledArray.get(currentIndex - 1).add(payload[i]);
        currentOn--;
    }

    return assembledArray;
}
```

Comment: Minor bug: If `payload.length == 21` and `splits=5`, then `size==4`.  But the `assembledArray` will have a size of 6 instead of 5 when the loop has completed.  The OP had explicit instructions about the last array to hold the residual elements.

Comment: Yeah I'm noticing that if i have : int[] payload = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24};
  int splits = 6; then I will get 5 arrays and not 6

Comment: @abagshaw This is a very tricky problem solve with considering all edge cases. I've tried for a few hours now

Comment: Ok the bug has been fixed (see the updated answer) and the output assembledArray.length always equals splits now. It now conforms to all desired outcomes. Tell me if this doesn't work.

Comment: @stackoverflow yeah same for me - I've been working on this for some time :) but I think I might have gotten it. Give the updated answer a shot.

Comment: Great thanks! With 14 elements (plus 0) split into 6 I get a lot piling up at the end. Is that what you want?

Comment: What should the output be for 14 elements (plus 0) and a split of 6?

Comment: well i think thats the best you can do with 14 split 6 ways. Although the big edge case comes out when you have 14 elements split 3 ways